# select from table based on values not in lookup table from single record

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to select from table A for a column value not in LKP table. The lookup table will have a list of values stored in a column in a single record.

Eg:

Table `LKP` will have something like this for a column `C1` having value as `'INVALID','UNKNOWN'` in a single record.

```
Table A:

ID
---
Bulbasaur
Charizard
Sqirtle
UNKNOWN
Ash
INVALID

Table LKP:

RULE    C1
----    ---
 1      'UNKNOWN','INVALID'
```

Desired output from below code:

```
select * from A where ID not in (select C1 from LKP where rule=1)

ID
---
Bulbasaur
Charizard
Sqirtle
Ash
```

I need to select all other values from `table A` except the one that are available in `C1` as single record.**The above code is not working. I am getting all the records returned from A.** Should the record value for `C1` be inserted differently in LKP table? It has to be in a single record mapped to `rule=1` in `where` condition as shown.

Please suggest.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have provided the dataset and desired result

Answer (score 0):

I discourage you from using `not in` with a subquery.  If any of the returned values are `NULL`, then no rows at all are returned in the query.

Does `not exists` fix your problem?

```
select a.*
from A
where not exists (select 1 from LKP where lkp.rule = 1 and lkp.c1 = a.id);
```

Comment: . . . `C1` having value as `'INVALID', 'UNKNOWN'` in a single record.

Comment: It won't have NULL. I am sure about that. But 'INVALID','UNKNOWN' in a single record. I need a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` and `explode` the csv string and then do the comparison.

```
with split_values as (select rule,c1,c1_split 
                      from LKP 
                      lateral view explode(split(c1)) tbl as c1_split
                     ) 
select * from a 
where not exists (select 1 from split_values s where s.c1_split=a.id and s.rule=1)
```